# find position of a substring in a string

Tags: python, string, find, position

i am having a python string of format

```
mystr = "hi.this(is?my*string+"
```

here i need to get the position of 'is' that is surrounded by special characters or non-alphabetic characters (i.e. second 'is' in this example). however, using

```
mystr.find('is')
```

will return the position if 'is' that is associated with 'this' which is not desired. how can i find the position of a substring that is surrounded by non-alphabetic characters in a string? using python 2.7

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here the best option is to use a regular expression. Python has [the `re` module](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) for working with regular expressions.

We use a simple search to find the position of the `"is"`:

```
>>> match = re.search(r"[^a-zA-Z](is)[^a-zA-Z]", mystr)
```

This returns the first match as a match object. We then simply use [`MatchObject.start()`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.start) to get the starting position:

```
>>> match.start(1)
8
```

Edit: A good point made, we make `"is"` a group and match that group to ensure we get the correct position.

As pointed out in the comments, this makes a few presumptions. One is that *surrounded* means that `"is"` cannot be at the beginning or end of the string, if that is the case,  a different regular expression is needed, as this only matches surrounded strings.

Another is that this counts numbers as the special characters - you stated *non-alphabetic*, which I take to mean numbers included. If you don't want numbers to count, then using `r"\b(is)\b"` is the correct solution.

Comment: You should actually use `\b` for that.

Comment: `re.search(r'\bis\b')` - otherwise you match the preceding symbol as well and the position is wrong.

Comment: @thg435 The asker said *non-alphabetic* not *non-alphanumeric*, so `\b` won't work - but good point on the position being wrong, didn't catch that, fixed.

Comment: besides, your expr fails to match at the beginning/end. You still need a lookaround here.

Comment: @thg435 The OP asked for `"is"` where *surrounded* by non-alphabetic characters - at the beginning or end that is not the case.

Comment: I wouldn't rely that much on what they _say_. As usual on SO, the question is vague and confusing, and it's your job as an answerer to guess (or ask) what they _actually_ trying to achieve.

Comment: @thg435 I added some clarification, but I will answer the given question. If the asker needs something else, they will have to make their question clearer.