# how to find specific string with a substring python

Tags: python, string, substring

I have similar problem to this guy: [find position of a substring in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10572199/find-position-of-a-substring-in-a-string)

The difference is that I don't know what my "mystr" is. I know my substring but my string in the input file could be random amount of words in any order, but i know one of those words include substring cola.

For example a csv file: `fanta,coca_cola,sprite` in any order.

If my substring is "cola", then how can I make a code that says

```
mystr.find('cola')
```

or

```
match = re.search(r"[^a-zA-Z](cola)[^a-zA-Z]", mystr)
```

or

```
if "cola" in mystr
```

When I don't know what my "mystr" is?

this is my code:

```
import csv

with open('first.csv', 'rb') as fp_in, open('second.csv', 'wb') as fp_out:
        reader = csv.DictReader(fp_in)
        rows = [row for row in reader]
        writer = csv.writer(fp_out, delimiter = ',')

        writer.writerow(["new_cola"])

        def headers1(name):
            if "cola" in name:
                    return row.get("cola")


        for row in rows:
                writer.writerow([headers1("cola")])
```

and the first.csv:

```
fanta,cocacola,banana
0,1,0
1,2,1
```

so it prints out

```
new_cola
""
""
```

when it should print out

```
new_cola
1
2
```

Comment: what does these numbers in first.csv:mean ? Are they desired results ?

Comment: You should explain how you get mystr, why do you expect 1,2 under "new cola".

Comment: When you call `headers1("cola")`, *of course* `"cola" in name`; `name == "cola"`! I think you need to rethink your approach. Try looking at what is actually in `rows`. `mystr` is just a filler variable - it is whatever string you are trying to process, in this case `name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example:

```
import csv

with open("first.csv", "rb") as fp_in, open("second.csv", "wb") as fp_out:
        reader = csv.DictReader(fp_in)
        writer = csv.writer(fp_out, delimiter = ",")

        writer.writerow(["new_cola"])

        def filter_cola(row):
            for k,v in row.iteritems():
                if "cola" in k:
                    yield v

        for row in reader:
            writer.writerow(list(filter_cola(row)))
```

**Notes:**

- `rows = [row for row in reader]` is unnecessary and inefficient (here you convert a generator to list which consumes a lot of memory for huge data)
- instead of `return row.get("cola")` you meant `return row.get(name)`
- in the statement `return row.get("cola")` you access a variable outside of the current scope
- you can also use the unix tool [cut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_%28Unix%29). For example:

  ```
  cut -d "," -f 2 < first.csv > second.csv
  ```

Comment: Thanks this was helpful, but what if i would have 2 filters?
for row in reader:
            writer.writerow(list(filter_cola(row)), list(filter_fanta(row)))
it gives me error (writerow takes only 1 argument). What am i not understanding here?

Comment: ``writer.writerow(list(filter_cola(row)) + list(filter_fanta(row)))`` – you have to concatenate the two returned lists with ``+``