# how to find a three letter in a sequence?

Tags: python

I have a sequence as follows :

```
my_file_m= "TCCATTCTCTACCCAGCCCCCACTCTGACCCCTTTACTCTGACCCCTTTATTGTCTACTCCTCAGAGCCCCCAGTCTGTA
TCCTTCTAACTTAGAAAGGGGATTATGGCTCAGGGTCCAACTCTGTGCTCAGAGCTTTCAACAACTACTCAGAAACACAA
GATGCTGGGACAGTGACCTGGACTGTGGGCCTCTCATGCACCACCATCAAGGACTCAAATGGGCTTTCCGAATTCACTGG
AGCCTCGAATGTCCATTCCTGAGTTCTGCAAAGGGAGAGTGGTCAGGTTGCCTCTGTCTCAGAATGAGGCTGGATAAGAT"
```

I would like to find where and how many specific three letters are , `TAA`, `TGA` and `TAG` . If there are any, I would like to color them up.

I started by loading the letters

```
my_file = open(my_file_m)
mine = my_file.read()
print(mine)
```

I could not use .count nor did I could use find because I have three inputs. Is there any idea how to find them and highlight them ?

Comment: "_[I couldn't] use find because I have three inputs_". Just call `find` three times, once per input.

Comment: Split the string three times using regex for each of those words. Your desired output will be the length of each of the splitted string - 1 (for respective words you used for splitting).

Comment: @nemo you can use function searchString($val, 3)

Comment: @akrun I felt like stupid, in a few second i received over 8 comments! I thought the question is very stupid that people have never faced! but if you think it is OK question, I can ask again

Comment: I've had this one as an interview question to solve on a whiteboard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my solution to your question:

Note: This code also finds overlapping sequences. Depending on whether you want to allow overlapping or not you will have to remove '?='

```
import re 

class bcolors:
    HEADER = '\033[95m'
    OKBLUE = '\033[94m'
    OKGREEN = '\033[92m'
    WARNING = '\033[93m'
    FAIL = '\033[91m'
    ENDC = '\033[0m'
    BOLD = '\033[1m'
    UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'

my_file_m= '''TTCCATTCTCTACCCAGCCCCCACTCTGACCCCTTTACTCTGACCCCTTTATTGTCTACTCCTCAGAGCCCCCAGTCTGTATCCTTCTAACTTAGAAAGGGGATTATGGCTCAGGGTCCAACTCTGTGCTCAGAGCTTTCAACAACTACTCAGAAACACAAGATGCTGGGACAGTGACCTGGACTGTGGGCCTCTCATGCACCACCATCAAGGACTCAAATGGGCTTTCCGAATTCACTGGAGCCTCGAATGTCCATTCCTGAGTTCTGCAAAGGGAGAGTGGTCAGGTTGCCTCTGTCTCAGAATGAGGCTGGATAAGAT'''


pat = re.compile(r'(?=(TAA|AAT|TGA|TAG))') # Very important, if you do not need overlaps then remove '?='
matches = re.finditer(pat,my_file_m)
result1 = [int(match.start(1)) for match in matches] # find all the starting positions of the string
result2 = [range(x,x+3) for x in result1 ] # find all the positions of the characters (given that we search for patterns of length 3, can be modified for other lengths too )
result3 = set().union(*result2) # generate a union

for chari in range(len(my_file_m)): # colorize based on if it is in a sequence or not
    if(chari in result3):
        print bcolors.OKGREEN + my_file_m[chari]  + bcolors.ENDC,
    else:
        print my_file_m[chari],
```

---

Cleaner:

```
import re 
import sys

my_file_m= '''TAATTCCATTCTCTACCCAGCCCCCACTCTGACCCCTTTACTCTGACCCCTTTATTGTCTACTCCTCAGAGCCCCCAGTCTGTATCCTTCTAACTTAGAAAGGGGATTATGGCTCAGGGTCCAACTCTGTGCTCAGAGCTTTCAACAACTACTCAGAAACACAAGATGCTGGGACAGTGACCTGGACTGTGGGCCTCTCATGCACCACCATCAAGGACTCAAATGGGCTTTCCGAATTCACTGGAGCCTCGAATGTCCATTCCTGAGTTCTGCAAAGGGAGAGTGGTCAGGTTGCCTCTGTCTCAGAATGAGGCTGGATAAGAT'''

pat = re.compile(r'(?=(TAA|TGA|TAG))') # Very important, if you do not need overlaps then remove '?='
lettersToColor = set().union(*[range(m.start(1),m.start(1)+3) for m in re.finditer(pat, my_file_m)])

for chari in range(len(my_file_m)): # colorize based on if it is in a sequence or not
    if(chari in lettersToColor):
        sys.stdout.write('\033[92m' + my_file_m[chari]  +'\033[0m')
    else:
        sys.stdout.write(my_file_m[chari])
```

Credit to : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/print-in-terminal-with-colors-using-python?answertab=votes#tab-top) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10572199/find-position-of-a-substring-in-a-string)

Output: 
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Using [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) function and [`collection.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) from the the standard library

```
import re
from collections import Counter

pat = re.compile(r"(TAA|TGA|TAG)")
c = re.findall(pat,my_file_m)

print(c)
print(Counter(c))
```

Output

```
['TGA', 'TGA', 'TAA', 'TAG', 'TGA', 'TGA', 'TGA', 'TAA']
Counter({'TGA': 5, 'TAA': 2, 'TAG': 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to split the DNA sequence by every three letter to map the genetic code?

If so, see the following code.

```
my_file_m= '''TCCATTCTCTACCCAGCCCCCACTCTGACCCCTTTACTCTGACCCCTTTATTGTCTACTCCTCAGAGCCCCCAGTCTGTA
TCCTTCTAACTTAGAAAGGGGATTATGGCTCAGGGTCCAACTCTGTGCTCAGAGCTTTCAACAACTACTCAGAAACACAA
GATGCTGGGACAGTGACCTGGACTGTGGGCCTCTCATGCACCACCATCAAGGACTCAAATGGGCTTTCCGAATTCACTGG
AGCCTCGAATGTCCATTCCTGAGTTCTGCAAAGGGAGAGTGGTCAGGTTGCCTCTGTCTCAGAATGAGGCTGGATAAGAT'''

mm = "".join(my_file_m.split())                 # delete the new line characters

messenger = map(''.join, zip(*[iter(mm)]*3))    # split every three letters

print messenger.count('TAA')
print messenger.count('TGA')
print messenger.count('TAG')
```

**output**

```
0
1
0
```

Comment: Thanks @Aaron, seems very interesting commands you used , thanks for your comment, I liked it already ;-)  however, why did you use the .split ? did you try to remove '''' characters  ?

Comment: In fact, there is a `\n` character at the end of the first three lines. `\n` means new line. I use `split` to remove the new line characters.

Comment: If you want to find the location of 'TAA', you can 
`import re`
`[m.start(0) for m in re.finditer("TAA", my_file_m)]`
It will show the index of the occurrence of 'TAA'.