# How can I remove substring of a value in dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, substring

I have a dictionary in python and I have to remove specific substring of a value:

```
dict1 = {'property': 'contents and properties', 'content': 'content metaData creationdate21023415:22:24creationdate metaDataend headingContent headingContent metaData creationDate22102312:02:05creationDate metaDataend DirContent DirContent'}
```

I have to remove the substring associated with key `'content'`. In that, I want to remove from `metaData` to `metaDataend`, and every time there is a re-occurrence of `metaData` in the same string, I want to remove that as well.

Expected End result:

```
{'property': 'contents and properties', 'content': 'content headingContent headingContent DirContent DirContent'}
```

Comment: Ok, so write some code to do that. Do you have a question?

Comment: I have made some changes in the original question. I am figuring out how to do that.

Comment: That isn't a question. SO isn't a tutorial service, please learn [ask].

Comment: The question is, how do I remove specific substring of a particular value in a dictionary.

Comment: And the answer is: you write some code to do it. This is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service, put some effort in yourself.

Comment: Well, I think it's a very valid question.

Comment: You're entitled to your opinion and I'm sure that your four whole days here have really informed that perspective. Please read the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 2):

I agree with jonrsharpe that this is not a place for asking people to do coding on your behalf. But in case you have no idea on which way to head with your problem, here are some hints you could look at:

You can use this to iterate your dictionary (splitting it into key and content):

```
for key, item in dict.iteritems():
    print "key:", key, " item:", item
```

That you could have found from this old question: [Iterating over dictionaries using 'for' loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops-in-python)

Next you will have to find where the words metaData and metaDataend exist in the "item". This you can do with the help of another older question:
[find position of a substring in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10572199/find-position-of-a-substring-in-a-string)

Then all you need to do is some slicing, which is described in this question:
[Explain Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation)