# python getting index of duplicate char for a specific position

Tags: python, indexof

I'm just starting out with python.
I'm trying to find the index of char present more than once

This is the sample string

```
08:28:57,990 DEBUG [http-0.0.0.0-18080-33] [tester] [1522412937602-580613] [TestManager] ABCD: loaded 35 test accounts
```

How should get the index of '[' and ']' present around 'TestManager' .

Comment: "TestManager" is not present more than once.

Comment: Do you want to get the last occurrence of '[' and ']'?

Comment: Maybe duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10572199/find-position-of-a-substring-in-a-string

Comment: i want get TestManager out of that long string. So yes it is the last occurrence of '[' and ']'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [find position of a substring in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10572199/find-position-of-a-substring-in-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

This might help.

```
s = "08:28:57,990 DEBUG [http-0.0.0.0-18080-33] [tester] [1522412937602-580613] [TestManager] ABCD: loaded 35 test accounts"
for i in reversed(s.split()):    #Split string by space and reverse the list
    if ("[" in i) and ("]" in i):                 #Check if "[" and "]" in string
        print(i)
        break
```

**Output:**

```
[TestManager]
```